# SQL Server Add row number each group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I working on a query for SQL Server 2016. I have order by **serial_no** and group by **pay_type** and I would like to add row number same example below

```
row_no | pay_type | serial_no
   1   |    A     | 4000118445
   2   |    A     | 4000118458
   3   |    A     | 4000118461
   4   |    A     | 4000118473
   5   |    A     | 4000118486
   1   |    B     | 4000118499
   2   |    B     | 4000118506
   3   |    B     | 4000118519
   4   |    B     | 4000118521
   1   |    A     | 4000118534
   2   |    A     | 4000118547
   3   |    A     | 4000118550
   1   |    B     | 4000118562
   2   |    B     | 4000118565
   3   |    B     | 4000118570
   4   |    B     | 4000118572
```

Help me please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign groups to adjacent pay types that are the same and then use `row_number()`.  For this purpose, the difference of row numbers is a good way to determine the groups:

```
select row_number() over (partition by pay_type, seqnum - seqnum_2 order by serial_no) as row_no,
       t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by serial_no) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by pay_type order by serial_no) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t;
```

This type of problem is one example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  Why does the difference of row numbers work?  I find that the simplest way to understand is to look at the results of the subquery.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8fa6c55e96d62e379266dad10da3973a) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY paytype ORDER BY serial_no) as row_no,
    paytype, serial_no
FROM table
ORDER BY serial_no
```

Comment: . . This answer is incorrect.  I don't know why it is upvoted, but it would return 6/7/8 for the second group of "A"s.

Comment: It doesn't order by paytype, would it not start counting again every time there is a change in paytype?

Comment: No, it would not.  You can run it in the db<>fiddle referenced in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your select list

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT 1) )
```

since you already sorting by your stuff, so you don't need to sorting in your windowing function so consuming less CPU,